# WebLogic 14c - Performance Tuning Test

Tags: performance, load, weblogic, weblogic14c

I want to do load test WebLogic 14c on Oracle Linux 8 (JDK 8). What are the best Load performance testing tools I can work with?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can have a look at LoadRuner (performance load testing tool).
WebLogic Admin console also support various monitoring capabilities along with JMX enablement. If the target of number of user known then you can work
as per the context you can use different tools such as JUnit.

Comment: Hello, I will review LoadRunner, I don't know if it works with WLS 14c and JDK 8u351, I will test it, thank you. We know the estimated load value from existing live systems. We actually use JMX, but we wanted to examine it with a different tool. Did you use JMeter? Would you recommend?